# Why does this type of inheritance work?

Tags: java, inheritance

First I define the superclass:

```
public class Living {
    double energy;

    Living(double energy) {
        this.energy = energy;
    }
}
```

Then I define the subclass:

```
public class Person extends Living {
    String name;

    Person(double energy, String name) {
        super(energy);  
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = this.getName() + " " +  this.energy;
        return s;
    }

}
```

Now if I do this:

```
Living creature = new Person(15.2, "Joe");
```

I will have created a creature of type `Living` by using the `Person` constructor. This is allowed because `Person` is a specialization of `Living`.

However I still cannot access the methods of the `Person` class - for example `creature.getName()` - through the point operator, because creature is declared as of type `Living` not `Person`.

```
System.out.println(creature.getName()); //not possible
```

But if I do this:

```
System.out.println(creature.toString());
```

I get

```
Joe 15.2
```

So instead of the `toString()` method of the `Living` class (which is not overriden), the `toString()` method of the `Person` class is called. I am having trouble understanding why this is the case.

I declare in the beginning that creature should be of type `Living`, although I use the `Person` constructor. If creature does not have a `name` attribute and its `toString()` method is not overriden, how can I get the above output?

Comment: That's how inheritance works. If methods are overridden in the child, the child method is used. But you can't access methods in the child that do not exist in the parent. Note that `toString()` exists in the parent because the parent itself inherits it from `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is indeed an instance of a `Person`, and thus has all of the `Person` methods. However, the reference is of the `Living` type. The compiler does not know its runtime type, and only allows you to access methods it "knows" will be available - i.e., the methods of the `Living` type.

It could, however, be coerced to treat this variable as a `Person`, but explicit casting:

```
System.out.println(((Person) creature).getName())
```

Answer (score 2):

For every object, there is a table (virtual table) which keeps information about the methods defined for this object.

If a parent method is overridden in a given object, this table will store the address of the overridden method, even if the object is referenced as one of the parent class. Every time a method is called, this table is used to find out how to access that method.

Therefore, in your case it will use the redefined method toString, because it has replaced the parent method.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It made a lot of sense and I did vote it up, however, the above answer gave a bit more helpful info that is why I accepted it.

Comment: No problem, have fun with Java :)

Answer (score 1):

`toString()` is declared in [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (from which all your classes inherit), that's why you can call it without being overridden in your class `Living` (some goes for methods such as `equals()`, `hashCode()`, etc.).

Notice, that if you would call the `toString()` on a different subclass of `Living`, such as `Animal`, which does **not** explicitly override `toString()`, you would get a default `toString()` result from `Object`.

```
public class Animal extends Living {
    String name;

    Person(double energy, String name) {
        super(energy);  
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // no toString override here

}
```

Calling `toString()` on `Animal`:

```
Living animal = new Animal(100, "Fido");
System.out.println(animal.toString()); // something like your.package.Animal@757dbeaf
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the main characteristics of Object-oriented programming.

When you do `Living creature = new Person(15.2, "Joe");` you are defining a variable which type is `Living`, but as you stated, specialized as `Person`. That means it won't have `Person` methods, only its specializations!

So, for example, if `Living` had a method

```
public String getName() {
    return "foobar";
}
```

and you called `creature.getName()` , the return would NOT be `"foobar"`, but the `"Joe"` instead. Because the 'specialization' of the method will be called, and not the super method itself.

However, only methods that are 'specialized' can be called: those who are particular to `Person` or any other subclass can't.

Answer (score 0):

The object is of type `Person`, but the reference if of type `Living`. As `Living` doesn't declare a `getName()` method, you get a compilation error, when you try to call it.

The `toString()` method is actually declared in `Object`, which is an *implicit* parent of `Living`, so `toString()` *is* declared. As the object is of type `Person`, and it overrides `toString()`, it is the one called.